# Cluster creation for Cloudera CDH5

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-cdh

I have a server machine with the following configuration.
    1) Dual Quad Core Xeon
    2) 24 GB Memory
    3) 500 GB Sata
    4) 256 * 2 RAID 1

The machine just arrived and we want to install CDH5 in it. We want create a sand box / dev cluster.
I am looking for some expert advice on

```
A) How many nodes we can create? We are targeting 4-5 nodes. Is that advisable.
B) I read Cloudera manager should be residing in the node with solid configuration.   Based on our configuration how much resource should be allocated for the same.
C) We will install Ubuntu 12.4.
```

We are fairly new to this process. Any help would be really helpful.

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 0):

The answer for A and B would be up to the purpose of the cluster. Let me answer in case the cluster is just for test purpose.

**A**: 4-5 nodes should be reasonable and Cloudera Manager can manage more than hundreds nodes.

**B**: Cloudera Manager server can be located with the other services (HDFS, MapReduce, or so). Please see the resource requirements [**here**](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CM5/latest/Cloudera-Manager-Installation-Guide/cm5ig_cm_requirements.html)

**C**: Ubuntu 12.04 is supported.

Answer (score 0):

A) You can start with 2 Master and 4 datanodes

B) Cloudera Manager will reside on one of the master nodes and run the supervising services and will give you a UI for managing services.

C) 16.04 LTS (Xenial), 14.04 LTS (Trusty), 12.04 LTS (Precise) are supported for ubuntu